# Problems connecting MySQL Workbench to Google Cloud SQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to connect to Google Cloud SQL but I am not sure what or where to get get the **username** and **databasename**. I am not sure which is which.

I am trying to connect using MySQL Workbench. I know where to get get the Hostname and the password and know that I had to add my IP address.

I am not sure which is the hostname and/or th username from **leafy-galaxy:invented-fake-table** (these are fake values)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

By default, all Cloud SQL instances have a user named root with a blank password and root permissions on the instance. It is strongly recommended that you set a strong password for the root user (you can do this in the console).

Once you have set the root password and connected using MySQL Workbench (or similar) you should create additional users to manage finer grained access to your database. See MySQL Access Privilege System for more information about managing MySQL users:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privilege-system.html

https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/access-control

Answer (score 0):

Joe's answer is correct with regard to the user and password.

As for the host, you can either use the IPv6 address that is automatically available, or you can request an IPv4 address (though there may be charges associated). The name that you mention (leafy-galaxy:invented-fake-table) is only usable from Google App Engine apps. This is covered in the "access control" link provided in the other answer.